# Posting variables to other pages through hidden forms?

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, post

I post this here for 2 reasons:
-to make sure that there is no problem with the trick, and
-to share the idea, in case it is OK

I thought it as a way to post to different pages, according to different tasks available to the user.
I find this trick with forms easy to implement and i made extensive use of it in a project (a beginner writing!) and it seems to work perfectly (locally testing).
But i did not find it clearly suggested anywhere, so i wonder if there is any potential problem with this code. Is it "legitimate" coding really?

Part 1 (visible)

```
<a href="" onclick="document.form1.submit();return false;">case 1</a><br />
<a href="" onclick="document.form2.submit();return false;">case 2</a>
```

Part 2 (invisible, at least some form(s))

```
<form style="display:none;" name="form1" method="post" action="page1.php">
<input type="hidden" name="v1" id="v1" value="<?="form 1 - value 1..."?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="v2" id="v2" value="<?="form 1 - value 2..."?>" />
</form>

<form style="display:none;" name="form2" method="post" action="page1.php">
<input type="hidden" name="v1" id="v1" value="<?="form 2 - value 1..."?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="v2" id="v2" value="<?="form 2 - value 2..."?>" />
</form>
```

In the visible part, any elements that accept onclick can be used, for example:

```
<input type="Submit this" value="process 1..." onclick="document.form1.submit();" />
<input type="Submit that" value="process 2..." onclick="document.form2.submit();" />
```

What seems to make this invaluable is that they can lead to different pages and with different variables:

```
<form style="display:none;" name="form1" method="post" action="page1.php">...</form>
<form style="display:none;" name="form2" method="post" action="page2.php">...</form>
```

If the answer is rather negative, would it be wise to start practicing on storing values temporarily in the database? I read that, theoretically, it is the safest way, but is this true?

Comment: You would be better off storing them in the session if you just want to pass values between pages.

`$_SESSION['v1'] = $whatever;`

Comment: Thanks. I also want to give *options* to the user saving mouseclicks at the same time.

Comment: Noticed now: "hidden forms" does not refer to the hidden form field, but to the whole forms as "display:none;".